# Microsoft 365 not asking for MFA while doing login

Tags: azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, saml, multi-factor-authentication, microsoft365

We built Single Sign-on feature through SAML. We are using AWS Cognito as Service Provider and Azure AD as Identity Provider.

In our application, a user clicks on Login with Microsoft button, and we redirect them to the AWS Cognito URL for MS 365 login. The login works successfully and the user is able to access the application.

I have configured an MFA device using this link https://mysignins.microsoft.com/security-info. But while doing SSO login, it's not asking for MFA. How to enforce MFA during login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

To setup the MFA in Microsoft 365, Login in to [**Microsoft 365 admin center**](https://admin.microsoft.com/#/homepage) with Admin Credentials.

*Go to Users -> Active Users -> Multi-Factor Authentication*

[image]

You can set the MFA for all the users or single user like below:

[image]

After setting the MFA when I tried to login, **I got the MFA prompt successfully** like below:

[image]

In https://mysignins.microsoft.com/security-info page you can select the device for MFA for a user like below:

[image]

For more in detail, please **refer** below link:

[How to Set Up MFA in Microsoft 365 by Sherian Batallones](https://www.avepoint.com/blog/protect/microsoft-365-mfa)

Comment: MFA is disabled for all the users in Azure. While doing the first-time login with the new account, Microsoft asked to set up MFA or skip for a few days. For the next login, it never asked for MFA. If MFA is disabled for my org. why is Microsoft still asking to setup MFA

Comment: Could you confirm that How to enforce MFA during login is your requirement right?

Comment: For the question in the comment: Sign-in as a Global Admin, Check whether there is conditional access policy that is enforcing the MFA.  *Azure Active Directory >Security> Conditional Access* and if there is any policy enforcing MFA try to remove them.

Comment: Under Azure, we have created a new organization to store guest/external users who can access our SSO-enabled app. I want to enforce MFA for all the users under my new org. The weird thing is currently only one user getting asked for MFA while login in. Users see Approve Sign-in request page on the UI but not receiving any notification in the Authenticator app.

Comment: Are all the users are enabled MFA in Azure?

Comment: I don't think so. I don't have Office 365 admin access but what I get to know from the IT department is that we have not made any changes for an individual user. Also when I try to switch from the Home org. to the new org.  in the Azure portal, it's asking me for Approve sign-in request but not receiving notification on my Authenticator app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251231/discussion-between-rukmini-and-harsh-kanakhara).

Answer (score 1):

In order to enforce MFA in Microsoft end, it needs to be configured in Azure.

Sign in to the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/) as a `Global administrator`. Then follow below steps:

- Browse to Azure Active Directory > Security > Identity Protection >
  MFA registration policy.
- Under Assignments Users - Choose All users or Select individuals and
  groups if limiting your rollout. Optionally you can choose to exclude
  users or groups from the policy.
- Enforce Policy - On
- Save

For more details please refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/identity-protection/howto-identity-protection-configure-mfa-policy).

In addition to that you can refer [Azure AD Multi-Factor Authentication user states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-userstates#azure-ad-multi-factor-authentication-user-states) to get a better idea on how each state would affect in different scenarios.